# Are treasures used as crafting components?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm a bit tight on gil at the moment, but I want to buy all cooking ingredients I come across so Ignis can unlock as many recipes as possible.

I *do* have quite a few valuables in the Treasures tab of my Inventory. However, I'm always wary about selling everything, because in some games, "treasures" can be used as crafting ingredients for things. I'd hate to sell something for 50 gil and then find out it's required to upgrade my spear and be forced to go back and get it again.

That said, is it okay to sell all of my Treasures in FFXV? Or are there some used as crafting components? If so, what are they, so I can hang onto them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, in fact, certain treasures that are used in quests or to upgrade weapons (also considered quests).

I found a list of all of these "Don't sell" treasures in the game [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932981-final-fantasy-xv/74647361):

> - Barbed Scythe
> - Cactuar Needle
> - Coeurl Whiskers
> - Cylinder
> - Dynamo
> - Earth Gemstone
> - Glass Gemstone
> - Magitek Core
> - Magnetron
> - Metal Scrap
> - Monster Claw
> - Repair Kit
> - Rusted Bits
> - Sky Gemstone
> - Spiked Armor
> - Sturdy Helixhorn

Thus, it looks like all other treasures are able to be sold without worry.

Answer (score 1):

**Any** treasures, cooking reagents and medicine can be used to add effect to spells during spells creation (such as different debuffs, up to 5x chained spells, benefits like experience etc). Each of many treasures provides certain effect. More of that, the more expensive treasure is - the more powerful effect it will add to spell. In this terms - there are no useless items in game.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it'd be even better if it mentioned that some treasures are also used to upgrade weapons. Specifically, I've been asked to gather metal scrap, rusted bit, and coeurl (sp?) whiskers, among other things. So even if you decide you don't care about the spell effects, you might still need it!

Comment: @Kat there are no missable items in game. If you use some items as spell reagents, you still can get same item somehow in the game (as far as I know, most difficult to get is Magitek Core, because it is available only on monster colosseum for insane price; still possible, though).

Comment: I didn't mean it'd be impossible to get another, just that you might regret selling it even if you don't want to use it for spells.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments in [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdkLvl-9PQAhXK7oMKHYmUC7IQFggwMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2FFFXV%2Fcomments%2F5fo0iw%2Fdo_treasures_have_any_uses_other_than_selling%2F&usg=AFQjCNGcCgV5M2Eva-5iLI9nKP5s4gVzgQ&sig2=m3aDkwCVeP4JCPXtr9J3PQ) thread, treasures can be used in conjunction with elements to modify spells and some treasures are used to upgrade weapons.

Comment: Could you quote some of the comments? Which treasures are used for crafting?

Comment: I had to use a Metal Scrap to upgrade a polearm I found with Paw Paw at Hammerhead. I've also used a Car Repair Kit, for a quest. Both of these items are in the Treasure category.